# Firebase: Read Data once activity started

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is there any ways to read data from `Firebase` once the `Activity` is loaded. At this moment I am using the regular `valueEventListener`, but in order for it to work, there has to be some sort of a change in the database

```
    mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).
                       child("Posts").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                arrayOfQuestionForms.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    QuestionForm tempQuestionForm = postSnapshot.getValue(QuestionForm.class);
                    arrayOfQuestionForms.add(tempQuestionForm);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

What I am looking for is some way to read data from `Firebase` without using listeners. I have looked at other similar posts but I don't think there is a clear answer for this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in order for it to work, there has to be some sort of a change in the database

This is not true and a common source of confusion for developers.

With your current code, Firebase will immediately start reading the data from the server. Once it gets that data, it invokes your `onDataChange()`.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events):

> This method is triggered **once when the listener is attached** and again every time the data, including children, changes.

Comment: Well, in that case is there any ways to load the data automatically because right now I have to click on something on my app to see the data

Comment: The listener you have shown should trigger straight away. If it doesn't something else is going wrong. Unfortunately it's impossible to say what that is from the code you've shared. I recommend reading from a fixed path initially and seeing if that works, so something like `mDatabaseReference.child("PublicData").addValueEventListener(...`. If that works, you know the problem is in the location (likely the UID).

Comment: You are actually right. I twisted some of the things and now so far it does what I was intended to do

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for reading data from a Firebase database without using listeners. Everything is about listeners when it comes to Firebase. It's true that when setting a value, we just need to use a method named `setValue()` directly on the reference. Unfortunately, there is no method within Firebase, let' say `getValue()`, which acts in the same way as `setValue()`.

To solve this, i recommend you using [addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)).

> Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location. This listener will be triggered once with the value of the data at the location.

Answer (score 1):

for such purpose I used different kind of listener - ChildEventListener. It has different @Override methods. The method onChildAdded returns every child-nodes of the node when called first time (i.e. on activity start).

Put attention - maybe you will need to slightly change the reference to DB (trim back one hierarchy level), to point to the parent node. If you expanded snapshot of your DB structure, I can look.
Here is updated code (sorry is made any typo - I couldn't test it as have no your DB :)

```
mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("Posts").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                arrayOfQuestionForms.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    QuestionForm tempQuestionForm = postSnapshot.getValue(QuestionForm.class);
                    arrayOfQuestionForms.add(tempQuestionForm);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hmm, it works the same way again. I have to press something in order to load the data. It is not automatic

Comment: Weird... for me similar code works automatically - I read  data from Firebase on on start, and put it in local SQLite, so app continue to work with SQLite only... What exactly you press in order to load the data?